# How to encode and decode ByteBuffer object using Chronicle wire

Tags: chronicle-wire

I am trying to write and read Java object into Chronicle wire format.

This object has one of the member variable of type ByteBuffer.

How to write ByteBuffer object into chronicle wire and read from Chronicle wire?

If I write ByteBuffer object as object into chronicle wire, I am not getting any errors.

When I tried to read it back from the wire as ByteBuffer.class, I am getting chronicle exceptions.

Is ByteBuffer marshaling supported by Chronicle wire?

Is it possible to encode it as byte[] and decode it as byte[]